# what does 'I don't respect a porn star the way I respect a career woman' mean

Tags: meaning, articles

Newspaper says

> I don't respect a porn star **the way** I respect a career woman or a woman of substance or a woman who isn't going to sell her body for sexual exploitation

I understand

> I don't respect a porn star. and I respect a career woman

In this case, what does "the way" mean?

Answer (score 7):

> I don't respect a porn star **the way** I respect a career woman

In this sentence, **[the way](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/the_way)** means "as", "in the way that". Thus,

> I don't respect a porn star **as** I respect a career woman.

which means "I don't feel the same kind of respect for a porn star **as** the respect I feel for a career woman", or "the respect that I feel for a porn star is not the same as the respect I feel for a career woman".

You can gloss it as "**in the same way that**":

> I don't respect a porn star **in the same way that** I respect a career woman.

Comment: @koji This is a great answer, but just as an additional note: you can often think of "the way that" as a synonym for "as much as." It definitely has that implication in this example.

Comment: And to follow on the comment by @joiedevivre, depending on the placement of the negative, **the way** can imply either a difference in degree or quality:  *I do like her but not the way I like you* or zero-degree:    *I don't respect him the way I respect her*.  In the latter example, the implication can be that you have no respect for him but do respect her.